# How to initialize a fragment based app?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can anyone help me with finding the entry point into a fragment based app? I am having an app with multiple activites. For small resolution devices one of he activities is loaded at startup, in this case a menu. This activity is declared as "launcher" in the manifest.

On a high resolution device I do not want to display the menu but all other activities should be displayed as fragments at the same time. For this I have declared a new layout in a `layout-w1000dp-h720dp` folder.
However from the manifest file it is still the menu which is loaded at startup and not this new layout with multiple fragments. So my app crashes at startup because it is trying to launch the menu but with the new layout with multiple fragments...

What am I doing wrong? Wow can the manifest file work together with this new layout?

I have attached an image how the app should look on a large screen device with the four fragments/activities. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the exact error you're getting?  The entry point for your app would be the Activity.  Since your app is based around fragments, you could have one Activity that holds the four Fragments you displayed above.  Your Manifest doesn't actually need anything extra to indicate that.  I'm also guessing that you have XML layouts premade for the Fragments.  If so, go to the layout of your Activity and specify the four fragments.

You would launch a single Activity, which then initializes your Fragments, and adds them in a FragmentTransaction.